# Are "critique my home-brewed content" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, homebrew

If I've developed some home-brewed content for my favorite RPG, such as a new class or monster for a d20 system, would posting it in a question asking for balance-related feedback be appropriate? While I believe it is certainly on-topic to the site, I fear a few things.

Most importantly I fear that it may lead to too subjective of answers, even though the question would be phrased with the intent of generating more a objective "yes, this is balanced" or "no, this is broken: fix ***_*__*_***" by comparing the content to similarly powered core content. I wouldn't be asking for stylistic or flavor feedback, but rather answers such as:

> You basically took a wizard and gave it perfect combat stats; there's no reason one would choose the core wizard over yours, therefore this class is broken. Reduce their spell-casting abilities to force players to make the trade-off.

Another issue is the fact that most class rules are far longer than typical length questions, and I would be tempted to post a link to them, which I know is frowned upon in case the link breaks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, homebrew questions are allowed.

I am not in favor of coming up with 100 different categories of question content we think are good or bad.

If a specific question is not a good SE question, it will be closed.  If it is a good one, it will thrive. The guidelines on what makes a good SE question are - while not "clear" exactly, because it's the FAQ as modified by random blog posts (good subjective/bad subjective) and site specific meta rulings - are at least reasonably scoped. If it's on topic and a question that doesn't trigger the dupe/not constructive/not a question/too localized rubrics, then it's fine.

You can ask for review of homebrews in a good SE-compatible way (just like people post code on SO) or you can do it in a bad subjective pointless way. I see no difference that the specific topic of homebrew vs system-agnostic vs RAW 4e vs setting design makes toward that end.

You basically admit above you fear that individual questions will be worded poorly and vaguely.  If they are, vote to close or edit to make them better.  But let's not cut more site scope out because someone "can ask a bad question."

To be a good homebrew question, the homebrew needs to be completely included and explained, and its goals stated.  To be good answers to a homebrew question, people need to either do mathematical/textual analysis or actually playtest it or something similar. Answers that are opinions on "how it might work out" will be subject to the usual censure.

Comment: A very excellent point - glad to have you as a moderator. =]