# How can I get to the SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer) without having to search up a link?

Tags: support, user-interface, site-statistics

I was going to go into the SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer) to try and compose a query related to [the discussion about unpinning accepted answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11726/what-is-our-stance-on-unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of), when I realized I couldn't figure out a way to navigate to SEDE.

In the past, I would typically nagivate there via a link I came across, but I didn't come across one today. I thought the burger menu would have a link, but I'm not seeing one; what am I missing?

Comment: Are you asking for a method that isn't just typing https://data.stackexchange.com into the bar?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov yes, although that link is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the bottom of the page, under "Stack Exchange Network", click "Other":

[image]

Then click "Data".

[image]