# Partial answer deleted as not an answer re: Medieval law and a tabletop role-playing game

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, deleted-answers

In the following question:

[Does Common Law apply to Nobles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139909/does-common-law-apply-to-nobles/)

The OP asks about applying a certain section of medieval law to the Warhammer Fantasy setting. I understood this to be a question about applying real-world medieval law, as otherwise there would be no need to specify: "Does this apply in the Warhammer Fantasy setting?", as the question is already tagged "wfrp-2e", "warhammer", and "wrfp".

As their question contained some fundamental misunderstandings of medieval law, based on examples I was aware of, and as those examples addressed half the question, [I gave those examples as a partial answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/139932) (10k+ rep only) so that the question might be improved, and partly answered. I specifically noted that the answer was a partial one.

This partial answer was then deleted as "not an answer". In my understanding, this would only be valid if the OP was only addressing WFRP, not medieval law and WFRP, as is my understanding.

A search on how to appeal a StackExchange deletion lead me to StackExchange Meta.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain I added a direct link to the answer, though it will show it only to those with un/delete vote privileges (10k+ rep). (Usually that’s sufficient since meta questions like this can only be expertly answered by those who have experience making deletion and undeletion decisions.)

Answer (score 16):

#### The answer was deleted because it didn't answer the question.

When a question on RPG.SE asks about a particular TTRPG system, it's expected that the answer be [relevant to that system](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7755/32840). Without knowledge of the system in question, the answer's content is likely uninformed or irrelevant, and [typically gets deleted](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/why-was-my-answer-deleted/8470#8470).

Although the question's title "Does Common Law apply to Nobles?" is not system-specific, the body and tags of the question are clearly asking about the Warhammer Fantasy setting. So when the question asks:

> Does this apply in the Warhammer Fantasy setting?

then a valid answer should contain some explanation based on the Warhammer Fantasy setting. The deleted answer did not do that. Specifically it said:

> I cannot address the case of WFRP, as I do not own any the books.
>
> There is a case I recall the generalities about, in England or Scotland
>
> I can't give a definite answer here

The answer's content was about real-world medieval European laws, and was not relevant to the TTRPG system in question, so it was considered off-topic and thus deleted.

Generally, if you want to provide [good, fact-based answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-rpg-stack-exchange) for TTRPG questions, it's best to answer only if you have sufficient knowledge of the system in question.

Comment: It would have been a good answer on Law Stack Exchange