# Is there any way to fix the Help Center "Scope" page?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, help-center

[Compared to the other PHB races, where does Mousemen homebrew race stands, in terms of balance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103652/compared-to-the-other-phb-races-where-does-mousemen-homebrew-race-stands-in-te?rq=1) has been closed as off-topic.  The only stated reason for close, is 'because "Evaluate my Homebrew" are offtopic'.  The quote on the autogenerated "closed" text is "This question does not appear to be about role-playing games within the scope defined in the help center." and includes a link to the "on-topic" page of the help center.  That page has at least some text specific to rpg SE, but absolutely nothing implying that "Evaluate my Homebrew" questions are offtopic.

It's not really an issue in this *particular* case, as the author of the question was one of the people who voted to close, but the fact that the helpful link on the close text telling you "go here to find out why your question was closed" has woefully insufficient information about what does and does not cause questions to be closed seems like a source of concern to me.

Is there any way to have that page changed so that it more accurately reflects the actual rules-as-enforced on the site?  If there's not, could we have such a way added somehow?

Comment: Moderators can edit that page. (It's the one help center page we can.) We do so at community request to correct issues with it like this one. We can take a look at doing that.

Comment: @doppelgreener Ah.  In that case, that seems like it might be worth doing.  Might also be worth pulling together a question on meta to actually codify what is and is not acceptable first, so that we get it all in one go.  I'm sure that this can't be the only rule that didn't make it in.

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm confused, "Evaluate my Homebrew" questions *are* on topic though right? So this question should not have been closed at all?

Comment: I think it depends how the question is worded, but yes, I believe they are (or at least can be) on-topic here. It can be tricky, though.

Comment: Actually, yes, homebrew evaluation can be fine and on topic — as long as it's reasonably scoped (e.g. not "so what do you think?"). See here: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/are-critique-my-home-brewed-content-questions-on-topic. We could update it to make mention of this.

Comment: I think part of the reason no clear guidance is in the On Topic page is in part due to the community not being fully settled regarding how we handle homebrew. Despite a number of meta discussions, my observation is that how to handle it continues to be an unsettled question.

Comment: Seems the linked question has been reopened (thanks to several reopen votes, presumably because homebrew evaluation questions are not off-topic).