# Is there something like Worldbuilding's reality check tag here?

Tags: discussion, questions

On Worldbuilding we have Reality Check tag. Someone can put his idea or small creation in the question, and ask if it is consistent, accurate, easy to understand etc.

Is there any way to ask such question on RPG? I made a "cheat sheet" of Pathfinder rules my group has hard time remembering and would like to ask if it's reasonably accurate, but I don't see questions like that here.

Comment: I'll note that as a daily user of RPG and a sometime-user of WB, I think they lie almost at opposite ends of the spectrum of network sites in terms of discussion, idea-generation, moderation, &c. I'm making no judgment here as to the good or bad of either approach, but I'd specifically caution "power users" of either site to pay close attention to local norms and ask for gut-checks *and listen to the answers* when acting on the other site. I've banged into the guardrails a few times over on WB =)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we have a tag for that, it'd probably just be tagged [pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder).

On the question itself: We can evaluate whether it's accurate and consistent with the rules (if that's what you meant by consistent).

I suggest not asking us if it's easy to understand. Ease of understanding is a personal matter for which there is not one best or correct answer; it's effectively opinion based. That part would risk the question being closed as a survey, if someone like me didn't just outright edit it out. You could still ask about that part on a forum though: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/1204)

Comment: I meant not only tag, but a philosophy behind it. On Worldbuilding, this tag says that philosophy for such question is not usual "I have this specific problem to ask", but rather "I think I have a solution but I want it get verified". And I don't know if it would be acceptable here.

Comment: I think the closest thing we've got is [homebrew review](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/1204), which is [on topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1398/1204). We can check your work, but we need to check your work based on either objective truth or subjective expertise: “are these summaries accurate per the rules or have I made some errors?” can be verified based on objective truth, but “do these read clearly?” is entirely opinion and is not something we should be asked to verify.

Comment: @Mołot It certainly seemed to be a big, accepted and expected thing in other RPG circles I've frequented (e.g. when SJG published the GURPS MA book, a playtester went around the world taking notes on the peculiarities of styles, some of them through *practical* testing), but I too am surprised not to see it so far here for some reason.

Comment: No, we do not have “alternate philosophies” here.  You can have things reviewed but normal SE rules apply.